# Как пользоваться DataGridView?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++

А можете расказать (или дать ссылку), как пользоваться DataGridView на языке C++ в VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Можем: [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

> Отображает данные в настраиваемой сетке.

Читаете статью - в конце есть пример кода по использованию класса. А перед примером - с десяток ссылок по различным особенностям работы с компонентом.